# How can I substitue using env variables set inside a script

Tags: shell, environment-variables, substitution

I have a script that sets several env variables that are available on a production server.  How can I run commands "inside" this script that access those env variables?  It looks like the substitution happens before running a command.  I'd like to run something like:

```
./osenv.sh echo "$POSTGRESQL_DB_PORT"
```

where `$POSTGRESQL_DB_PORT` is set by `osenv.sh`

Comment: You simply can not that way. But you can instead use `./osenv.sh POSTGRESQL_DB_PORT`: no substitution will be made and, inside the script, you can do whatever you want (i.e., look up the content of the variable POSTGRESQL_DB_PORT).

Comment: unclear to me why you want to do this, but are you aware of the `source envFile` (or it's shortcut `. envFile`)? OR are you trying to achieve something like `DB_PORT=23232 /path/to/script/that_uses_DB_PORT` ? These 2 are your only options, or it is unclear what you're trying to achieve. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can either run the variable-setting script within the context of the current process by sourcing it (in which case the script doesn't even need to be marked executable):

```
. ./osenv.sh #same as `eval "$(cat ./osenv.sh)"`
echo "$POSTGRESQL_DB_PORT"
```

or

you can change the script to execute its arguments at the end:

```
#...
POSTGRESQL_DB_PORT=9999
#...
exec "$@"
```